# Lock based on a flag

Tags: c#, multithreading, if-statement, locking

I want to lock few lines of code based on a `flag` from App config. So based on that `flag` I run the application asynchronously or not. So i need to lock execution of few lines of code by checking the `flag`. So i need to write code repetitive. Below is the sample

```
if (flag) {
    lock(dataLock){
        //few lines of code
    }
} else {
    //repeat the above code gain here (few lines of code)
}
```

Is there any alternative way where I can save my repeated codes.

Comment: What about placing the lock above the `if`? So the whole if would be wrapped within the lock.

Comment: If i wrap flag check within the lock then always it will be locked i believe. I want to decide to lock or not based on a flag. Let me know if i am wrong.

Comment: A, my bad. I think you should wrap the _"//repeat the above code gain here (few lines of code)"_ into a method.

Comment: Using method is a solution, but i want to know is there any other best way to implement it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (flag)
    Monitor.Enter(dataLock);

// few lines of code

if (Monitor.IsEntered(dataLock))
    Monitor.Exit(dataLock);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Monitor.Enter instead of Lock() {} ? Enter and exit with the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could call a function with your outsourced code from within the lock and even from within the else statement. That would at least reduce your overhead and repetitive code.

```
if(flag==true){
    lock(dataLock){
        fewLines();
    }
}else{
    fewLines();
}
```

[...]

```
public void fewLines(){
   // put your few lines here.
}
```

that would run the function from the locked context.

Answer (score 1):

The `Monitor.Enter` aproach is best, but you could also do this:

```
Action fewLinesOfCode = () =>
{
    //few lines of code
};

if (flag)
{
    lock (dataLock)
    {
        fewLinesOfCode();
    }
}
else
{
    fewLinesOfCode();
}
```